# Connecting to Redis Cluster via Sentinel

Tags: redis, cluster-computing, predis

I have a redis cluster of three master nodes and three slaves. I also have three Sentinel servers (each on a separate machine) monitoring the redis cluster. Using Predis, I am able to connect to the cluster via a single Master Node's IP/Port. But I want to know if I can actually connect Predis to the CLuster via a Sentinel IP/port?

Answer (score 0):

Redis Cluster handles failover itself without Sentinel, so you don't need to use Sentinel via Redis Cluster.

Only thing you need to do is choosing library which can support Redis Cluster.